# using BETWEEN 'date' AND 'date' after Subquery, dont get it to work properly

Tags: php, mysql, date

This is the workflow I was working after...

> Get data between time and time -> sort by newest -> filter out the duplicates phonenumbers -> search for three different variables string -> print result using php.

First I used this, however it didn't sort by latest record:

```
  SELECT id, phone, text 
  FROM phones 
  WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2016-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-06 23:59:00' 
  GROUP BY user 
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

After searching and testing I got it to work with a subquery:

```
SELECT id, phone, text 
FROM phones WHERE timestamp IN(SELECT
                       max(timestamp) 
                       FROM phones 
                       GROUP BY phone )  
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

However now I'm not sure where I shall put the function:

```
BETWEEN '2016-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-06 23:59:00'
```

I tried in the subquery and outside in the main. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: In your first query you have a GROUP BY user but you don't have an aggregate function, i.e. you are not doing a count, sum, average, etc. In your second query you will only match on those rows that have the max timestamp. You seem to want all the records sorted desc and that second query won't get you that. If you can provide some sample data in a table that would help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1 for how to get the newest row for each phone. Just add the `BETWEEN` condition to the subqueries.

Comment: thanks for the link, it worked after doing like this.

SELECT id,phone,text,timestamp,MAX(timestamp) 
FROM phones 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2016-10-10 20:43:33' AND '2016-10-10 22:44:52' 
GROUP BY phone
ORDER BY timestamp
DESC

Answer (score 0):

Try using str_to_date

```
SELECT id, phone, text 
FROM phones 
WHERE date(timestamp)  BETWEEN  str_to_date( '2016-10-01' ,'%Y-%m-%d') 
                              AND str_to_date( '2016-10-06'  '%Y-%m-%d') 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```